# SQL Query that ignores symbols

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for something that will only return alphanumerical characters in an SQL Query

Right now I have two coloums, `ttitle` and `tsub` where the `ttitle` could be `Champ's Shack` and the `tsub` could be `"Grilled Cheese"`

and I need it to return that field as `champsshackgrilledcheese`

So far I have gotten it down to `champs'sshack"grilledcheese"`

and I still need to remove those characters...

here is the code that gets it that far...

`REPLACE(LOWER(CONCAT(TRIM(ttitle),TRIM(tsub))), ' ','')`

What can I do to get it to return without symbols?? and only alphanumeric, I want to try and avoid SQL functions if possible

Comment: Are the single/double quotes the only symbols? If so, then you are already using `replace`, so why not just add to it to replace the single/double quotes?

Comment: I wanted to, however couldn't wrap my head around it, because I want to replace the symbol `'` but am using `'` in the actual code, I am prolly over thinking it

Comment: REPLACE( `col_name` , ' ' , '' )

Comment: Read about **[escaping characters in string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html)**

Comment: O right duh, let me try it and see what I can get

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau to replace single quotes you will need to escape it `REPLACE(yourcol, '\'', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(CONCAT(TRIM(ttitle),TRIM(tsub))), ' ',''),'\'',''),'"','')
```

*Yes, this is extremely ugly.* But since MySQL does not have support for regular expressions ([unless you add an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)), you need a call to `REPLACE` for every single character you want to replace.

At least, if you want to avoid user-defined functions, as specified in your question.

Comment: This is working however I am having an issue, I had escaped the value when it was added to the database so now I am getting this...`champs\sshack\grilledcheese\` because yes it is removing the 's and the "s but its not removing the \ and the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html says to use \\ but that throws an error

Comment: Try `\\ ` or if you are embedding your SQL in some other programming language, you maybe have to escape it twice: `\\\\ `.

Comment: wild escaping it twice worked...not sure why that is but thanks, the comments got me in the right direction, you just summed them up in an answer